# How can I get the value of array object?

Tags: magento2, ajax, json

Im try to pass sql query value as  an AJAX request, It have a array object I need to pass only the value, below code for that

```
public function execute()
    {
$resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection'); 
        $connection = $resource->getConnection(); 

        $sql = "SELECT price_component FROM base_price WHERE width =".$this->getRequest()->Width." AND height =".$this->getRequest()->Height; 
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $resultJson->setData($result);
    }
```

if I used below code in .phtml class

```
.done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

result will be like below

```
[{…}]
0
:
{price_component: "122"}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

If i use result[0] index it will be like JSON object like below

```
{price_component: "132"}
price_component
:
"132"
__proto__
:
Object
```

> I just need to get value to the console how can I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try in your ajax success response like below,

```
.done(function(data) {
          var priceValue = data.price_component;
          console.log(data.price_component);
});
```